# How to access enum declared in a d.ts file - Nativescript

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

I have declared an enum in a **d.ts** file

```
declare enum myenum
{
    TYPE_ONE,
    TYPE_TWO,
}

declare class MobileAPI extends NSObject {....}
```

Now I am accessing the enum in a **.ts** file like bellow.

```
this.mobileAPI.addType(myenum.TYPE_ONE,NSString.stringWithString("someString"));
```

I can compile the app, but getting following JS error

```
JS ERROR ReferenceError: Can't find variable: myenum
```

What's am I doing wrong here, please share some idea on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's am I doing wrong here, please share some idea on this

You are creating a *declaration*. These should only be used if you have corresponding [JavaScript code available](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/ambient/intro.html).

## Fix

Dont use declare and use a file `.ts` (not `.d.ts`)

```
enum myenum // Fixed
{
    TYPE_ONE,
    TYPE_TWO,
}
```

## More

If you are not the author of the `.d.ts` file, *make sure you load the corresponding JS* for the `.d.ts` file.

Comment: I am creating a nativescript plugin for native iOS libarary. .d.ts file is auto generated

Comment: Then make sure the corresponding JS is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can do inside your d.ts :

```
export const enum myenum {
  TYPE_ONE = "TYPE_ONE",
  TYPE_TWO = "TYPE_TWO"
}
```